# Add additional information to a UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uiimage, cgimage

I'm trying to add some information to a `UIImage` I am doing some experimentation with to add details like the number of `UILabel`'s present on the screen and their frames.

I tried using `setValue:forKeyPath:` but this does not work since `UIImage` is not key-value compliant. What is an efficient way to do this?

Adding metadata using the `CGImageMetadata` API's seems to need me to convert the `UIImage` to `NSData`. Also, I would like to access the data without saving it every time. Can anyone point me to a good way to do this?

Comment: Why add the data to the UIImage instance? Why not store that information elsewhere? Create a class that have a UIImage and NSInteger properties, for example. Or put the properties in the view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get use of associated objects to complement objects of classes source of which you don't have access to with some additional data (with use of [`objc_setAssociatedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418509-objc_setassociatedobject?language=objc) to set and [`objc_getAssociatedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418865-objc_getassociatedobject) to read the data):

```objc
UIImage *image = [UIImage new];
NSString *extraData = @"extra info";

objc_setAssociatedObject(image, @"example", extraData, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
NSLog(@"%@", objc_getAssociatedObject(image, @"example"));
```

For convenience it can be effectively wrapped with a property by extending the class with a category:

```objc
//  UIImage+TDWExtraData.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface UIImage (TDWExtraData)

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *tdw_extraData;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

```objc
//  UIImage+TDWExtraData.m

#import "UIImage+TDWExtraData.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static void const *const kExtraDataKey = &kExtraDataKey;

@implementation UIImage (TDWExtraData)

- (NSString *)tdw_extraData {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kExtraDataKey);
}

- (void)setTdw_extraData:(NSString *)data {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kExtraDataKey, data, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}


@end
```

---

**P.S.** It's not correct to say that `UIImage` is not KVC compliant only because it doesn't support `setValue:forKeyPath:` for non-existing key paths. It's perfectly compliant for key-paths the class has defined:

```objc
UIImage *obj = [UIImage new];
NSLog(@"%@", [obj valueForKey:@"size"]); // prints size
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the setValue:ForKeyPath:! That helps a lot.